# Generics and Class.asSubclass

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

I've always thought the following should work. I get an object which I know is a `Class<X>` where `X` extends some class `Xyz`. In order to make it type-safe I wanted to use Class.asSubclass like in the following method:

```
private Class<? extends Xyz> castToXyzClass(Object o) {
    final Class<?> resultClass = (Class<?>) o;
    final Class<? extends Xyz> result = Xyz.class.asSubclass(resultClass);
    return result;
}
```

However, in Eclipse it doesn't work, the only solution I see is an unchecked cast. I'd bet the above code must work, I've used something like this already... no idea what's wrong here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`asSubclass()` operates on the object it's called on, not on its parameter - not what one is used to, but it reads quite well. You just have to do this:

```
final Class<? extends Xyz> result = resultClass.asSubclass(Xyz.class);
```

Comment: I personally think it would read better if it were `resultClass.asSubclassOf(Xyz.class)`.

Answer (score 10):

The `asSubclass` is a bit of a confusing name because you're not obtaining a Class object representing the subclass, you're obtaining the *same* class object that is retyped to reflect that it is a subclass of some *parent* class.

In fact, this method is fairly single purpose (and I think you've found it)...it's to take a raw or wildcarded class and get a better type parameter **with a runtime check**.  It's not needed when you don't have gaps in your type information:

```
class Super {}
class Sub extends Super {}

//...
Class<Sub> subClass = Sub.class;

//both work, but the latter introduces a redundant runtime check
Class<? extends Super> subOfSuper1 = subClass;
Class<? extends Super> subOfSuper2 = subClass.asSubclass(Super.class);
```