# Parameterized Upper Bounded Generic Class from String?

Tags: java, generics, parameterization

I've seen these two answers:

- [Generics and Class.asSubclass](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939704/2782193)

  ```
  final Class<? extends Xyz> result = resultClass.asSubclass(Xyz.class);
  ```
- [Generics and Class.forName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733827/2782193)

  ```
  Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) Class.forName(className).asSubclass(ifaceClass);
  ```

What I'm actually trying to do is:

```
    final Class<? extends Xyz<?>> clazz = Class.forName(name).asSubclass(Xyz<?>.class);
```

but `Xyz<?>.class` is not valid Java. Is there a magic incantation I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your problem.

If you mean, that your code-line is not compiling, you can fix it by doing a cast as you can see in the following example:

```
package test;

public class Test<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final Class<? extends Test<?>> clazz = (Class<Test<?>>) Class.forName("test.Test").asSubclass(Test.class);
        //... do something with the class
    }

}
```

How to avoid the warning for an "unchecked"-cast you can read for example here:
[How do I address unchecked cast warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings)

Comment: Sorry, I'm really asking is there anyway to avoid the cast ?

Answer (score 0):

`Class<? extends Xyz<?>>` is meaningful only if Xyz is itself a generic type.

Comment: `Xyz` is indeed a generic parameterised type.